# How to get Kubuntu 19.10 to configure an external monitor correctly on startup?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I have been fighting with an external monitor issue for months, unable to solve the problem, it's deeply frustrating. My setup is as follows:

- Kubuntu 19.10 (Eoan) / Win 10 (on a separate HDD, not shared)
- Lenovo T480s with Intel 620 Graphics
- Thinkpad USB-C dock
- Dell 27 2560x1440

The problem is when I boot up with the laptop lid closed and monitor connected via the dock, the external monitor is recognised but it has no taskbar. I have to run the following commands in order to have the external monitor set as the main primary monitor with a taskbar:

`xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output eDP1 --off --output DP1 --off --output DP2-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP2-2 --off --output DP2-3 --off --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI1 --off --output DP2 --off`

then

`killall plasmashell`

then

`plasmashell`

I hate Windows, but one thing it can do well - multiple monitors. I actually have a second external screen which works perfectly with Win 10, but I have long since given up any hope of getting two external screens working under Ubuntu. I will be happy with just one.

How can I get the external screen to operate as the main primary monitor, with a taskbar, on boot, without the need for manually setting it up each time?

Comment: In case you don't get help here, consider asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the advice..